# Trying to use css to fade one div out and another div underneath in

Tags: css, html, opacity, fade

I have searched and searched... I have two divs. One is on top of the other. I want to make one div fade out when you roll over it and the other div fade in, then fade out back to the first div when you roll off of it. The problem is, I cannot seem to use the img src="" in my html maybe because it is a wordpress site.

With my current code, it seems the first div fdaes out and the second div fades in but then the second div fades out again. I would like it to stay until you roll off of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am trying to learn this and it is very confusing.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="webdesignlink">
    <div id="webdesignlinka">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://www.sitename.com">
            <div id="webdesignlinkb"></div>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```css
#webdesignlink {
    height: 216px;
    width: 505px;
}

#webdesignlinka {
    height: 216px;
    width: 505px;
    background-image: url(images/webdesignlink.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 1;
}

#webdesignlinka:hover {
    opacity: .0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#webdesignlinkb {
    height: 216px;
    width: 505px;
    background-image: url(images/designlinkB.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
}

#webdesignlinkb:hover {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about positioning the `div`'s on top of each other and only fading the top one out on `:hover`? The one in the background can be visible all the time. Example:

### HTML

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

### CSS

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.blue:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGEff/)

Answer (score 0):

Cogito...

```
#webdesignlinka {
  opacity: .0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#webdesignlinka:hover {
  opacity: .0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

?